# Async/await with multiple for loops

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, runtime

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how aysnc/await works for my specific scenario. I have some for loops that I want to run parallel of each other but I also have other for loops that are dependent on the data create from one of the parallel for loops.

```
Loop 1 {
/* Delete some rows from a SQL Table */
}

Loop 2 {
/* Delete some rows from a SQL Table */
}

Loop 3 {
/* Add some rows to a SQL Table */
}

Loop 4 {
/* Update some rows from a SQL Table */
}
```

What I want to happen is Loop 1, Loop 2, and Loop 3 run in parallel instead of sequentially. I don't want Loop 4 to run until Loop 3 has finished. How could this be achieved with async/await. I am trying to improve runtime of this code but I need to use for loops to iterate through data in the database.

Alternatively, if there is a way to reduce the time complexity using a different method instead of for loops I am open to suggestions.

Comment: loop1(); loop2(); loop3().then(loop4);

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Answer (score 1):

await Promise.all(promiseLoop1, promiseLoop2, promiseLoop3);

await promiseLoop4;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Edit:

In addition, you can build the SQL command string using loops but only call  SQL once.

You may also want to look into SQL Transactions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have tried this method but still loops 1-3 are running one after each other. I am trying to run them in parallel. If they run in parallel will this reduce the time complexity of my code or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: @jbowden97 if you are creating a new Promise for each loop, they should be running asynchronously. It may only seem like they are running synchronously if your loops are relatively short. As an example, to see the asynchronous behavior use setTimeouts. Make Promise 1 resolve after 10 seconds, Promise 2 resolve after 5 seconds, and Promise 3 resolve after 1 second. The Promises will resolve in the following order: Promise 3, 2, then 1.

Comment: @jbowden97, please share your codes about your approach in the question.

Comment: Actually, this approach is not quite what OP want. `loop4` still need to wait for `loop1` and `loop2` finish even `loop3` finish early before. `loop4` should only wait for `loop3`.

Comment: @ikhvjs OP also asked if there "is a way to reduce the time complexity using a different method". Since OP doesn't actually provide code, one can only infer that loops 1-3 are actually making separate SQL calls. It's better to build a SQL command string and make one call. This would still require for loops 1-3 to finish first before appending the SQL command string with loop 4, then finally calling SQL with the complete command in one call.

Comment: If you read again this sentence `What I want to happen is Loop 1, Loop 2, and Loop 3 run in parallel instead of sequentially. I don't want Loop 4 to run until Loop 3 has finished`, I think OP want loops 1-3 run in async, but `loop4` just need to wait for `loop3`.

Comment: @ikhvjs Refer you to my previous statement. This question is asked by OP. They are free to choose the best answer that suits their needs. If you disagree, you are free to post your own answer.

Comment: I just leave a reminder for OP's question. You may be right in the first place.

Comment: It is true that I want loop 4 to happen after loop 3 completes. Loop 1 and Loop 2 can happen at anytime while my code is running.